# Is there any ways to replace nested if in excel-vba?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hye I am new to excel vba so don’t how to use it efficiently, I got almost 50,000 row of data for the TestID. I want to do some dynamic looping to determine the TestType. Let say if the TestID is 001 to 100 the TestType is TEST A,if TestID is 101 to 220 the TestType is TEST B, if TestID is 221 to 260 the TestType is TEST C.

Is there a way to do this without using nested if using excel vba?

I using nested if to do this but the data is too many

[image]

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("001",[@TestID])),"Test A",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("002",[@TestID])),"Test A",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("003",[@TestID])),"Test A","")))
```

If the TestID is 001 to 100 the TestType is TEST A,if TestID is 101 to 220 the TestType is TEST B, if TestID is 221 to 260 the TestType is TEST C

Comment: Use a `Select Case` statement if you are using VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common, non-VBA method of handling that problem is with a lookup table.

This assumes your `TestID` values are numeric and not text strings.

For your conditions, the formula might be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,{1,"TEST A";101,"TEST B";221,"TEST C";261,"Unspecified"},2)
```

[image]

As pointed out by @chrisneilson, if you want to return a blank for values <1 or >=261, you can modify the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,{0,"";1,"TEST A";101,"TEST B";221,"TEST C";261,""},2)
```

Comment: @chrisneilsen Good point.  That can also be done for the `261` entry.  I will edit my response with credit.